# Which one is correct - "Committed to help .." or "Committed to helping .."?

Tags: word-choice

Consider "I'm committed to help somebody to do something/with something." vs. "I'm committed to helping somebody. to do something/with something."

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=am+committed+to+help%2Cam+committed+to+helping&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cam%20committed%20to%20help%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20committed%20to%20helping%3B%2Cc0) would seem to show that both are used, with the 'committed to + gerund' variant far more common today.

Answer (score -1):

I think the phrase should be:

**I am committed to help** somebody with something.
**I have committed to helping** somebody with something.

Comment: This isn't correct. There is no reason to add in *have*.